# How to add predefined _id to a user on Meteor.startup for a fixture DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to do a fixture database with posts and those posts will belong to the created users....both collections will be created  on Meteor.startup so I need to know the user IDs in order to add them to the posts and make a relation between them, but I don't know how to create the users with a custom ID so I can connect to the posts...here is my code:

Posts:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
if ( Posts.find().count() < 100 ) {


Posts.insert(
  {
    createdAt: new Date(),
    postStatus: "lorem ipsum blah blah",
    type: "post",
    authorId: "aWcGJaqXeM64uGE9M" // this is an example of an Id i am trying to add to a user so the post get connected to that user
  });
```

Users

```
if ( Meteor.users.find().count() < 100 ) {
    Accounts.createUser(
      {
  _id: "aWcGJaqXeM64uGE9M",
  username: "Davenport",
  emails: "Davenport@gmail.com",
  password: "Mcdowell"
    },
    );
});
```

You can see I create users and I try to add a specific ID to it but when I run the app the ID field won't be taken in consideration and it will override that to a completely new user ID

Comment: Maybe you can save the user firstly, then assign the saved user id to post,  finally, save this post...

Comment: Yes but I need to create 1000 users and 5000 posts so I am looking for something less time consuming

Comment: Try to replace the specific ID with `new ObjectId()`?

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific what is ObjectId()? never heard of it and can't find about it on google or meteor docs

Comment: I post one answer here, hope it could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Accounts.createUser will return the id of the newly created user.

So you can do something like this:

```
var userId = Accounts.createUser({
  username: "Davenport",
  emails: "Davenport@gmail.com",
  password: "Mcdowell"
});



Posts.insert({
    createdAt: new Date(),
    postStatus: "lorem ipsum blah blah",
    type: "post",
    authorId: userId
  });
```

Comment: Yes but all the inserts are done on the server on Meteor.startup.. how can I know the userId to add it to the post if the users and posts are created at the same time on Meteor.Startup?...this is why i need a predefined userId so I add it to the posts before...

Comment: Loop thru all the users you want to create, saving the userIds in an array or object.  Then loop thru your posts and add in the authorids by referencing the saved userIds